# How to focus on next row input in the same column by hitting enter key

Tags: javascript, html

I am saving Paper result I want  to save it fast like we do in ms excel by pressing enter key do focus 
on next bottom cell

```html
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Muhammad Umar Abdur Rahman</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="ReadingMarks257" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="WritingMarks257" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="PaperMarks257" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Muhammad Abu Bakkar</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="ReadingMarks258" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="WritingMarks258" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" value="0" name="PaperMarks258" onkeydown="Next(event)" class="input">
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have already tried

```js
function Next(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
        var Element = $(this).closest('tr').next().find('.input');
        Element.focus();
    } else {
        $("#Msg").html('another Pressed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nextElementSibling.focus()`:

```
function Next(e) { 
    if (e.which === 13) {
        e.target.nextElementSibling.focus();
    }
    else {
        $("#Msg").html('another Pressed');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey @NibrasAffairs use `:first` selector.

```js
$('.input').keydown(function (e) {
      if (e.which === 13) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="half">
     <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Muhammad Abu Bakkar</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="ReadingMarks258"  
          class="input"></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" name="WritingMarks258"  
      class="input"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="PaperMarks258" class="input"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Muhammad Abu Bakkar</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="ReadingMarks258"  
          class="input"></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" name="WritingMarks258"  
      class="input"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="PaperMarks258" class="input"></td>
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Muhammad Abu Bakkar</td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="ReadingMarks258"  
          class="input"></td>
         <td><input type="text" value="0" name="WritingMarks258"  
      class="input"></td>
        <td><input type="text" value="0" name="PaperMarks258" class="input"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```